# OpenXML Copy from Excel to Word preserving format

Tags: c#, openxml

writing a quick app to copy from xlsx to docx and I am an OpenXML Newbie.
Most cells contain formatting, such as paragraphs, linebreaks, bullet points, numbered lists etc.

I can copy stuff already as I like, getting the InnerText of a Cell into a Run(new Text(cellText)) in Word.

But in Word I then see all content, but as one simple consecutive (running) text. Thus is there a way to simply keep the content formatted as in Excel?

Cheers

Comment: Really nobody? Not even a hint?

Comment: You can read the font, size etc and then apply it to your run. As such there is no direct way

Comment: I am curious as to how Microsoft Word does this when you copy and paste over a range of cells. Why wouldn't these methods be included in OpenXML? I have a similar question, but with a more specific use case... it doesn't seem like many people are knowledgeable about OpenXml - any thoughts about as to why? Is there something else that is used?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057183/are-there-any-shortcuts-or-classes-for-converting-the-xml-from-a-range-of-cells
@FortyTwo